# Testbench error caused by the line order of the always begin and initial begin block

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, test-bench

I am trying to write a testbench for systemverilog module and I realized a strange behaviour depending on order of the ***always begin*** and ***initial begin*** block. Here is my code block which works correctly.

```
 top test(clk, reset, writedata, dataadr, pc, instr, readdata, memwrite);
        
    always begin
            reset = 0;
            clk = 0;
            #10;
                    
            reset = 0;
            clk = 1;
            #10;
    end
    
    initial begin
        clk = 0;  
        reset = 1; #10; 
    end
```

If the always begin block written before the initial begin block the code works perfectly fine and outputs this[image]

But if we change the order of the ***always begin*** and ***initial begin*** blocks

```
 top test(clk, reset, writedata, dataadr, pc, instr, readdata, memwrite);
   
    initial begin
        clk = 0;  
        reset = 1; #10; 
    end
     
    always begin
            reset = 0;
            clk = 0;
            #10;
                    
            reset = 0;
            clk = 1;
            #10;
    end
```

[image]

In which the values are set to undetermined. Don't these two blocks work independently? Why does their order of writing cause a problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a simulation race condition.  The `always` block and the `initial` block assign the `reset` signal to different values at the same simulation time (0ns).

Your first code sets `reset` to 1 at time 0, then to 0 at time 10ns.  Your design presumably has an active-high reset, and it properly reset the internal design signals to known value at time 0.

The waveforms for your 2nd code appear to keep the `reset` signal at 0 for the whole simulation; I assume the signal below the clock is `reset`.  In this case, the internal design signals are not properly reset, and they retain their initial unknown values.

In the 2nd block, the simulator sets reset=1 in the `initial` block at time 0, then the value of `reset` is overwritten by the `always` block at time 0, setting reset=0.

In any case, I recommend you simplify the code like this to avoid the race condition:

```
always #10 clk = ~clk;

initial begin
    clk = 0;  
    reset = 1;
    #10;
    reset = 0;
end
```

---

Due to nondeterminism, even your 1st code could produce the bad result.  There is no guarantee that the simulator will execute the `always` block before the `initial` block.